# With Bokeh, how to save to a png or jpg instead of a html file?

Tags: python, bokeh

I need to export pictures of the graphs and plots I am creating with Bokeh.

Usually I do

```
output_file("test.html")
```

However, I want to copy that graph into an Excel Sheet.
It does not have to be interactive anymore, though that would be brillant.
How do I export the graph as a picture? Using code, not clicking on "preview/save".

Comment: IMHO the html is the only (file) option at the bokeh [session management](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/reference.html#session-management), you can use [this](https://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png/) to convert html to jpg.

Comment: I don't have permissions to install PyQt.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5742090/1982962) post.

Comment: Seems to me like it is only for text.

Answer (score 15):

As of Bokeh `0.12.6`, it is now possible to export PNG and SVG directly from
Python code.

Exporting PNGs looks like this

```
export_png(plot, filename="plot.png")
```

And exporting SVGs looks like this

```
plot.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(plot, filename="plot.svg")
```

There are some optional dependencies that need to be installed.
You can find more information in the [Exporting Plots section of the User Guide](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html).

Comment: the export_png function increases my running time about 15 seconds, do you experience the same?

Comment: Yes, I experience this too

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are willing to work with JavaScript. And, for instance, if you want to save many canvas (each canvas element has a plot) at the same time you can use the JavaScript method `canvas.toDataUrl()` to convert the canvas to png as base64. When you get all the images you can do whatever you want with them. These images have 96dpi and it cannot be changed, so if you want more resolution you will have to update the sizes of all the elements of the plot before the convertion as well: fonts, axis, plot size...

If you use this approach you do not need to install `selenium` and `phantomjs` dependencies in your python environment.

Also, be aware that if you use `export_png` and you export the plot with a bigger size, [the axis and fonts are not going to be proportionally bigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58115711/4891717)