# How to save bokeh plots in non html formats

Tags: python, bokeh

I am able to generate plots using Bokeh. Now I want to save them as .png, .jpeg etc files. Is there a way to do that using Bokeh itself ?

Comment: So far, none. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060173/with-bokeh-how-to-save-to-a-png-or-jpg-instead-of-a-html-file), which may count as your question's duplicate, given that said post is fairly recently as well.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan Thanks.