# python: use windows api to render text using a ttf font

Tags: python, windows, winapi, fonts, rendering

What would be a full example, going from nothing to ending up with a bitmap in memory, of opening a particular `.ttf` file and rendering some text using that font, using the native Windows API? I'm currently slogging through the windows API, so it's a race between me and the rest of stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you *have* to use the native Windows API? If not, you can use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Comment: @Harpyon: aye, see my [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747739/python-render-non-anti-aliased-font-to-internal-image/5747805#5747805) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748973/why-is-my-truetype-font-of-size-11-rendering-different-than-windows)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Done and done for rendering a font (requires PyWin32):

```
import ctypes
import struct
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32ui

from PIL import Image


def RGB(r, g, b):    
    return r | (g << 8) | (b << 16)

def native_bmp_to_pil(hdc, bitmap_handle, width, height):
    bmpheader = struct.pack("LHHHH", struct.calcsize("LHHHH"),
                            width, height, 1, 24) #w,h, planes=1, bitcount)
    c_bmpheader = ctypes.c_buffer(bmpheader)

    #3 bytes per pixel, pad lines to 4 bytes    
    c_bits = ctypes.c_buffer(" " * (height * ((width*3 + 3) & -4)))

    res = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetDIBits(
        hdc, bitmap_handle, 0, height,
        c_bits, c_bmpheader,
        win32con.DIB_RGB_COLORS)
    if not res:
        raise IOError("native_bmp_to_pil failed: GetDIBits")

    im = Image.frombuffer(
        "RGB", (width, height), c_bits,
        "raw", "BGR", (width*3 + 3) & -4, -1)
    return im    


class Win32Font:
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight=win32con.FW_NORMAL,
                 italic=False, underline=False):
        self.font = win32ui.CreateFont({
            'name': name, 'height': height,
            'weight': weight, 'italic': italic, 'underline': underline})

        #create a compatible DC we can use to draw:
        self.desktopHwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
        self.desktopDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.desktopHwnd)
        self.mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(self.desktopDC)         
        self.drawDC = self.mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

        #initialize it
        self.drawDC.SelectObject(self.font)

    def renderText(self, text):
        """render text to a PIL image using the windows API."""
        self.drawDC.SetTextColor(RGB(255,0,0))

        #create the compatible bitmap:
        w,h = self.drawDC.GetTextExtent(text)
        
        saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(self.mfcDC, w, h)        
        self.drawDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

        #draw it
        self.drawDC.DrawText(text, (0, 0, w, h), win32con.DT_LEFT)

        #convert to PIL image
        im = native_bmp_to_pil(self.drawDC.GetSafeHdc(), saveBitMap.GetHandle(), w, h)

        #clean-up
        win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())

        return im        

    def __del__(self):
        self.mfcDC.DeleteDC()
        self.drawDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.desktopHwnd, self.desktopDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(self.font.GetSafeHandle())

    def __del__(self):
        win32gui.DeleteObject(self.font.GetSafeHandle())
```

usage:

```
>>> f = Win32Font("Arial", 15)
>>> im = f.renderText("this is just a test")
>>> im.save("c:/hope.png")
```

result:

[image: GLORY]

brilliant!!!

To render a particular `.ttf` file I'll need to dig around more.

UPDATE: Updated to calculate the bmp size:

[image: woot]

Comment: you don't want to render a ttf file

Comment: @David: you can read my mind!?! kidding aside, what do you mean?

Comment: fonts are often made up of multiple ttf files. Generally you want to render a font face, e.g. Arial. Look and see the different ttf files that make up arial.

Comment: you should just install the font and get on with it. It's what you are expected to do.

Comment: @David: that's fine, but how do i get the font face from the font file?

Comment: where does the file come from? How come you don't know the face name?

Comment: i want to make a program to try to discover what font is being used by taking a screenshot and matching the text up. i could just enumerate all installed fonts, i guess, and try them all. my app would come with a set of fonts to try (if an app uses a less common one). ideally i could just get the font faces programmatically so i dont have to hard-code them and so i can add fonts to the set (e.g. if someone runs the app and they installed 10000 random fonts i might not want to waste time trying all the wingding variations)

Comment: this program is doomed to failure. There are so many different factors beyond font face.

Comment: @David: hmm indeed considering how many attempts it took me to match notepad's output..

Comment: you're really got absolutely no hope whatsoever! This would be an entire university research department's project for 10 years! Maybe I'm being dramatic but if it were me I'd run away.

Comment: @David: hehe aye i dont mean to do it perfectly. i misspoke - the ultimate goal is to OCR the font, not to find the font face. just if it so happens that my technique works then i'll use it. otherwise i will ocr the letters by hand. just seeing if i can save myself some trouble.

Comment: You can upload the image directly to SO, you don't have to hotlink somewhere.

Comment: MS docs on CreateFont function are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Guys, please help. I try to use this code and get this trace:
File "C:/develop/pypdf417/render.py", line 20, in native_bmp_to_pil
    c_bits = str(ctypes.c_buffer(" " * (height * ((width * 3 + 3) & -4))))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 70, in c_buffer
    return create_string_buffer(init, size)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 63, in create_string_buffer
    raise TypeError(init)
TypeError:  

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here is updated version for Python 3 of the accepted answer (full credit to @Claudiu). I'm using "Segoe UI" as an example to show how we can perfectly match the native Windows user interface:

```
import ctypes, struct, win32con, win32gui, win32ui, PIL.Image

def native_bmp_to_pil(hdc, bitmap_handle, width, height):
    bmpheader = struct.pack("LHHHH", struct.calcsize("LHHHH"), width, height, 1, 24)
    c_bmpheader = ctypes.c_buffer(bmpheader)
    c_bits = ctypes.c_buffer(b" " * (height * ((width*3 + 3) & -4)))
    res = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetDIBits(hdc, bitmap_handle, 0, height, c_bits, c_bmpheader, win32con.DIB_RGB_COLORS)
    if not res:
        raise IOError("native_bmp_to_pil failed: GetDIBits")
    im = PIL.Image.frombuffer("RGB", (width, height), c_bits, "raw", "BGR", (width*3 + 3) & -4, -1)
    return im    

class Win32Font:
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight=win32con.FW_NORMAL, italic=False, underline=False):
        self.font = win32ui.CreateFont({'name': name, 'height': height, 'weight': weight, 'italic': italic, 'underline': underline})
        self.desktopHwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
        self.desktopDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.desktopHwnd)
        self.mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(self.desktopDC)
        self.drawDC = self.mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
        self.drawDC.SelectObject(self.font)

    def renderText(self, text):
        self.drawDC.SetTextColor(0)
        w,h = self.drawDC.GetTextExtent(text)
        saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(self.mfcDC, w, h)        
        self.drawDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)
        self.drawDC.DrawText(text, (0, 0, w, h), win32con.DT_LEFT)
        im = native_bmp_to_pil(self.drawDC.GetSafeHdc(), saveBitMap.GetHandle(), w, h)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
        return im

    def __del__(self):
        self.mfcDC.DeleteDC()
        self.drawDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.desktopHwnd, self.desktopDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(self.font.GetSafeHandle())

f = Win32Font("Segoe UI", 15)
im = f.renderText("Hello World")
im.save("test.png")
```

Comment: do you know how to make it work with unicode? i really cant get it work.