# Python PIL using different font

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image I would like to add text to but I want to use both a different style font and a something bigger than the smallest thing known to mankind.  Heck you can hardly read the text it's so darn small.  I can print the text to the screen but I can't change the font style or the size of it as I don't know where the fonts are stored.  I would think there would be more than one font/font size standardly available for use with Python/PIL.  Where are they stored at?  I am on a Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5430111/15055):

```
image = Image.new("RGBA", (600,150), (255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("resources/HelveticaNeueLight.ttf", fontsize)

draw.text((10, 0), txt, (0,0,0), font=font)
```

Looks like you can specify any `.ttf` file and any `fontsize` you want using the above modules and functions.

Comment: Got it once I found the directory where to go to to find the font files.