# Adding Kurdish text (right to left) to image is returned separated strings

Tags: python, image, arabic

I'm using PIT to put Kurdish(sorani, arabic-like) text on an image, but the text on the image is separated from each other. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

```
font_size = 100
img = Image.open("cute cat.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("./KGoran.ttf", font_size, encoding="unic")

text = "ڕۆژتان باش ئازیزان"
reversed_text = reversed(text)

fill = (0,0,0)
font = font

string_text = ""
for i in reversed_text:
    string_text += i

draw.text((0, 0), string_text, fill, font)
img.save("added text to image.jpg")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIL can't handle shaping Arabic-like fonts, (unless they fixed it recently).  I've seen one library, like [this reshaper library](http://mpcabd.xyz/python-arabic-text-reshaper/), which will combine characters correctly.  Other solutions include using pango or pycairo to deal with the font, [see this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414639/python-imaging-library-text-rendering).