# Font rendering issue with PIL

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

I am trying to generate a `PNG` image which contains some custom text.
While creating the new image canvas there are multiple options  to choose the mode of  the image (Ex: P, PA, RGB, RGBA etc).
When I use the `P` mode, the rendered text is not anti-aliased.
Size of the result image is considerably smaller when used `P` mode compared to other modes like RGB, RGBA so, this would be my preference.
I would like to know why the font rendering is dependent on the color pallet? Is `P` mode (8-bit pixels ) with 256 colors are not sufficient to render the font?
When I use several of these `png` images as frames and generate a `GIF` image out of it, the quality of the image is reduced drastically. 
[image: With <code>'P'</code> mode]
[image: With <code>'RGB'</code> mode]

As discussed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414639/python-imaging-library-text-rendering) thread, I do not want to resize the image which is a time consuming operation.

Below is the code which I have used:

```py
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('Assets/somefont.ttf',82)
  b = Image.new('P',(680,120),color=255)
  #b = Image.new('RGB',(680,120),color=255)
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(b)
  #draw.fontmode = "0"
  draw.text((b.width/2, (b.height-50)/2), "88", fill=0, font=fnt)
  f = BytesIO()
  b.save(f, format='PNG')
```

Comment: Did you mean to put "Pip" in your question title?

Comment: Pretty clear from the `python-imaging-library` tag that the questioner meant "PIL"; I edited to fix that.

Comment: @djangodude, your edit is correct. That's my bad. But do you know the fix?

Comment: I put an answer, but re-reading your question I'm confused because you mention "creating the `GIF` image" but your code writes `PNG`. Maybe you can clarify your question a bit more and I will try to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- use mode 'PA' for your Image
- convert to 'RGB' prior to saving

So your code becomes something like:

```
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('Assets/somefont.ttf',82)
b = Image.new('PA',(680,120),color=255)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(b)
draw.text((b.width/2, (b.height-50)/2), "88", fill=0, font=fnt)
b = b.convert('RGB')
f = BytesIO()
b.save(f, format='PNG')
```

I got reasonable-looking results with this approach (different font, obviously, but you can see that it's anti-aliased):
[image: image using PA mode and RGB format]