# Writing text to image with alternating formatting

Tags: python

I want to write multiline text to an image and highlight some parts of it with green or red (to produce a diff and show the edits in a block of text, in an image). The idea would be to input a text (with some way to say which parts should have which formatting), an image width and height, and to get the image as an output.

I can envision how I can do this with `PIL`'s `ImageDraw.Draw().text()` and `.textsize()` to calculate when to go to a new line as well as the sizes and positions for each `.rectangle()` (which would be the highlighting), but it all seems fairly tiresome, and I can't be the first person who needs to do this. Is there some better package to do this?

Comment: Not sure this will help, but check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414639/python-imaging-library-text-rendering